# Cycle through options with Rhino Grasshopper Python

Tags: python, grasshopper, rhino3d

I would like to cycle through design options using a grasshopper python component in the following way:

```
for i in range(1, 15):
    a = i
```

where `a` is the name of the output.
`a` would then be linked, for instance, to the diameter of a circle.

On the rhino viewport, I would expect to see the circle changing diameter at each step of the iteration.

Obviously what I show doesnt work.

I also tried using `time.sleep(1)` in between each steps, as well as `ghenv.Component.ExpireSolution(True)`.

Both of them fail / crash the rhino software.

Any help or pointers hugely appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Grasshopper computes a component and renders results after that's completely done.
For your purpose you need to output the entire list like so:

```
a = [i for i in range(1,15)]
```